# How to verify if there is an element < x in a set C++

Tags: c++, iterator, stdset, lower-bound

Is there an element that is smaller than a given x in a std::set s
If there isn't print "x is the smaller than any element", if there is then print "the biggest element that is smaller than x".
By the way, you also know that x is not in the set

is :

```
cin >> x;
auto it = s.lower_bound(x);  
it--;
if (it == s.begin()) 
    cout << "x is the smallest element in s\n"
else
    cout << *it;
```

ok ?

More questions :

if it = s.begin(), then if you do --it, what will it be ?
if *it is the smallest element in the set then if you do --it what will it be ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `--it` if `it == s.begin()` because the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`lower_bound` will return an iterator pointing after all the elements that are less than `x` -- that is, pointing at the first element greater than or equal to `x`.  So if it returns `s.begin()`, then all the elements are >= `x` (none are less). So its good to answer your question directly:

```
if (s.lower_bound(x) == s.begin())
    cout << "x is smaller than all elements of s";
```

Answer (score 0):

If `it` is an iterator to the first element of a container, then `--it` is Undefined Behavior, meaning you should make sure your program doesn't do that.  If the program does, anything might happen, and it's the program's fault, not the compiler or library.

So the correct way to find the biggest element smaller than `x` in a `std::set s` that does not contain `x` is:

```
auto it = s.lower_bound(x);
if (it == s.begin())
    std::cout << x << " is smaller than all elements of s\n";
else
    std::cout << "The largest element in s smaller than " << x << " is "
              << *std::prev(it) << "\n";
```

(This is also correct if `s` is empty: there is no element of `s` at all, so no element smaller than `x`, and "smaller than all elements of `s`" is vacuously true.)